# get closest match in regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get the closest match between two words in regex

here is an example what I am trying to do:
[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/kpIJpj/1/)

the problem is `"Track number"` will find the first match and continue looking for `"subtitles"`

the things I need just grep,

```
Track number: 3 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 2)
|  + Track UID: 1382186431
|  + Track type: subtitles
```

so basically grep closest `"Track number"` to the `"subtitles"` word

but i don't know how

Comment: @user3325376  Please include an expected output when your input has more than one Track No (please post the input too).  Are you wanting an array of all matches? or just one match?  Is this happening in a loop?  Please clarify because this will determine the best method for your question.  (Also, please do not add question details as comments -- rather, please edit your question so that all future SO readers can get the full story from reading the question alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help you out..

**Solution 1:** `Tricky solution,(for  testing purpose i have added a sample string just in the middle to show this solution is working fine.)`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/792660)

```
$string='"
+ EBML head
|+ EBML version: 1
|+ EBML read version: 1
|+ EBML maximum ID length: 4
|+ EBML maximum size length: 8
|+ Doc type: matroska
|+ Doc type version: 2
|+ Doc type read version: 2
+ Segment, size 627752082
|+ Seek head (subentries will be skipped)
|+ EbmlVoid (size: 4044)
|+ Segment information
| + Timecode scale: 1000000
| + Muxing application: libebml v1.0.0 + libmatroska v1.0.0
| + Writing application: mkvmerge v4.1.1 (\'Bouncin\' Back\') built on Jul  3 2010 22:54:08
| + Duration: 7279.440s (02:01:19.440)
| + Date: Sat Sep 18 15:52:16 2010 UTC
| + Segment UID: 0x83 0x63 0x0c 0xd7 0x2c 0xb9 0x73 0xb5 0xab 0x7f 0xd0 0xa4 0x3d 0x1c 0xf9 0xf6
|+ Segment tracks
| + A track
|  + Track number: 1 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 0)
|  + Track UID: 1383154402
|  + Track type: video
|  + Lacing flag: 0
|  + MinCache: 1
|  + Codec ID: V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
|  + CodecPrivate, length 45 (h.264 profile: Main @L3.1)
|  + Default duration: 40.000ms (25.000 frames/fields per second for a video track)
|  + Video track
|   + Pixel width: 1280
|   + Pixel height: 696
|   + Display width: 1280
|   + Display height: 696
| + A track
|  + Track number: 2 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 1)
|  + Track UID: 3159569538
|  + Track type: audio
|  + Codec ID: A_AAC
|  + CodecPrivate, length 2
|  + Default duration: 21.333ms (46.875 frames/fields per second for a video track)
|  + Audio track
|   + Sampling frequency: 48000
|   + Channels: 2
| + A track
|  + Track number: 3 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 2)
|  + Track UID: 3633586111
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + Lacing flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_TEXT/UTF8
| + A track
|  + Track number: 4 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 3)
|  + Track UID: 1098098602
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + Default flag: 0
|  + Lacing flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_TEXT/UTF8
|  + Language: dut
| + A track
|  + Track number: 5 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 4)
|  + Track UID: 2228128442
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + Default flag: 0
|  + Lacing flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_TEXT/UTF8
|  + Language: fre
| + A track
|  + Track number: 6 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 5)
|  + Track UID: 1507679374
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + Default flag: 0
|  + Lacing flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_TEXT/UTF8
|  + Language: ita
| + A track
|  + Track number: 7 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 6)
|  + Track UID: 3667538853
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + Default flag: 0
|  + Lacing flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_TEXT/UTF8
|  + Language: swe
|+ EbmlVoid (size: 1239)
|+ Cluster
';
$result=null;
$matched=false;
for($x=0;$x<substr_count($string, "|");$x++)
{
    preg_match_all("/Track number(?:.*?[\|]){".$x."}/s", $string,$matches);
    foreach($matches[0] as $match)
    {
        if(preg_match_all("/Track number.*?subtitles/s", $match,$matches))
        {
            $result[]=$matches[0];
            $matched=true;
        }
    }
    if($matched==true)
    {
        break;
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: I think mickmack was on to something

Comment: @hmedia1  I dont understand friend what you are trying to say.... are you trying to say somethinig about mickmackusa ?

Comment: @SahilGulati we get problem in multi-subtitle (multi-match) case, please check https://regex101.com/r/Z6DLrr/1 and https://regex101.com/r/Z6DLrr/2
the first one just grep the last match, the second one works fine for all matches except the first match

Comment: @user3325376 I suggest you to use my second solution Hope that will help you out..

Comment: @SahilGulati the second solution will return only one result too

Comment: @user3325376 I have updated my post hope that will help you now.. You can check it, you can try this demo here https://eval.in/792660

Comment: @SahilGulati thanks you, second solution is working, but is there any direct regex way exist to solve this problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144026/discussion-between-user3325376-and-sahil-gulati).

Answer (score 3):

### This will match as many instances as you have:

`Track number:(?:.(?!Track number:))*subtitles`

[Here is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/Prhmcr/1)

This will return the following (as many regions there are between `"Track number:"` and `"subtitles"`

```
Track number: 3 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 2)
|  + Track UID: 1382186431
|  + Track type: subtitles

---- Other tracks in between ----

Track number: 3 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 7)
|  + Track UID: 1887396985
|  + Track type: subtitles
```